# Select "Today" in Vaadin’s calendar widgets, DateField and InlineDateField?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7, datefield

[image: Screen-shot of Vaadin InlineDateField widget]

Vaadin has a pair of nice calendar widgets, [DateField](https://vaadin.com/api/7.2.5/com/vaadin/ui/DateField.html) & [InlineDateField](https://vaadin.com/api/7.2.5/com/vaadin/ui/InlineDateField.html).

One feature I've not detected: Can the user get back to "Today" after perusing various months and dates?

Or must I add my own separate "Today" button? At least I could do so for `InlineDateField`, but not `DateField`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe so, I think you would have to code it yourself.

I **think** its the same for JodaTime too.

I'm sure you already figured this out, but here is some simple code for anyone else!

```
    final DateField x = new DateField();

    final InlineDateField y = new InlineDateField();

    HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();
    layout.setSpacing(true);

    layout.addComponent(x);
    layout.addComponent(y);

    Button button = new Button("Today");

    layout.addComponent(button);

    button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            Date date = new Date();
            x.setValue( date );
            y.setValue( date );
        }
    });



    this.setContent(layout);
```